# Lenovo G50-70 boot device missing after reboot, but present after shutdown and poweron using linux

Tags: boot

I have Lenovo G50-70 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and everything went ok. After reboot I get blue message "Boot Device Missing". If I shut down laptop and then power on, everything works and Ubuntu boots without problem. If I try to reboot it, I get same message that boot device is missing.

I tried Ubuntu Server (and Desktop) 20.04 and same thing. Only OS that can boot after restart is Windows 10.

I reset BIOS to defaults and no changes.

Some a year or so ago I had Ubuntu 20.04 and Pop_OS! 20.04 and reboot worked as far as I can remember.

How to fix it?

Here are BIOS settings at the moment: [BIOS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVNx7.jpg) [BIOS 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkQz6.jpg) [BIOS 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGtib.jpg)

I also tried changing SATA Controller Mode to Compatibility, Secure Mode to disabled, Reset To Factory Mode, Restore Factory Keys. Still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked to see if Lenovo have provided any BIOS updates that you haven't applied?

Comment: You also have Fast Boot enabled from your screenshots. You should try and disable that and see if it helps, because it's known to be incompatible with Linux.

Comment: @galexite I have newest BIOS update. I chacked.

Comment: @galexite I tried disabling Fast Boot and still no change.